Is there a Sales Cloud Campaign object > Data Cloud DMO equivalent?
Working on my first Data Cloud implementation, and the client has a loyalty program, but doesn't use SFDC Loyalty Management, so that bundle isn't an option and it's fairly exhaustive for my use case of 3 objects in SFDC they use for their loyalty program.
I'm trying to map the SFDC Campaign and Campaign Member Objects, but there is just no clear Data Cloud equivalents out of the box.  Which is surprising as they first billed it as a "Marketing CDP" back when I learned it. I was going to use the Promotion DMO, but that's all mapped up to the Loyalty Data Model, which is OVERKILL for my use case: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_loyalty_data_model.htm&type=5
Have you all just created custom Campaign/Campaign Member DMOs? Any advice for getting Sales Cloud Campaign and Campaign Members mapped in?
I need it to link to a few objects they use for Campaigns that drive loyalty member point redemption and using those data points for Segments.
Thanks in advance!
